# Java: Removing percent sign after printf formatting

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
return String.format( "%.2f", result);
```

For some reason it is printing

```
37.00%
```

I do NOT want the percentage sign at the end of this. Why is this occurring and how do I remove it?

Comment: That expression doesn't print anything and it doesn't add a % character. You have code elsewhere that prints that % character.

Comment: Show the code that uses this method return and prints on screen.

Comment: Also, where is the print statement itself executed?  Show us the code that calls your method.

Comment: I personally often forget to add `"%n"` to the end of the format string. It's different from `println` like that.

Comment: For some reason switching the printf to a println fixed it! Thanks guys

Comment: Wait a second... what type is result? Besides that what locality have you set? Note that this question has not been answered even if you found a work around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the '%' is coming from somewhere else.  When I run the following code, "37.00" is printed to the console:

```
public class Main {

  public static String formatResult(float result) {
    return String.format( "%.2f", result);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(formatResult(37f));
  }
}
```